# How to properly pass variable between action methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one ListController that lists items, and a ManageController that handles different actions for the selected item from  ListController.

So, how do i pass the variable to the ManageController (and its sub actions) so that it is there **even when a user opens the the same URL in a different browser**.

This excludes Sessions and Cookies directly.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed example? If you want to share information between controllers, in the *same* request, you should use TempData.

Comment: If you only have a URL, then the query string or some other method of putting the information in the URL (i.e. routing via /Edit/5) is pretty much your only option.

Comment: figured , but i will have to pass this parameter/id around to every action

Answer (score 2):

You could try saving the data to be shared in TempData which is like saving data in the Session but the data will be deleted automatically in the end of the request where it was read.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FirstAction()
{
    ...
    TempData["sharedData"] = data;
    return RedirectToAction("SecondAction");
}

public ActionResult SecondAction()
{
    var data= TempData["sharedData"];

    return View(data);
}
```